# Can you suggest a solution for json data display in vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My vue js code is

```
    <script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    VueGoogleMap.load({
    key: 'AIzaSyDcEkMFV_WyhNdZrr8VLaCYOw4FP75u748'
  });

  Vue.component('marker', VueGoogleMap.Marker);
  Vue.component('map', VueGoogleMap.Map);

  var map = new Vue({
    el: '#map',
    data: {
        data: [],
        markers: [],
        center: {},
    },
     mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      var self = this;
      var id = window.location.href.split('=').pop()
             console.log(id)
      $.ajax({
            url: "https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get/10",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (e) {
                if (e.status == 1) {
                    self.data = e.data;
                    self.markers = [{position: { lat: e.data.lat, lng: e.data.lon}}]
                    self.center = {lat: e.data.lat, lng: e.data.lon}
                    console.log(e.data)
                    console.log(e.markers)
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('Error occurred');}
            }, error: function(){
            console.log('Error occurred');
            }
        });
    })
  },
  });
    </script>
```

My html code for displaying values are
But I need to display marker based on the json data.

```
<div id="map">
    <div class="m-single-article" id="map">
    <p>{{data.bussinessName}}</p> 
    <p>{{data.pid}}</p>
     <map :icon="{path:'M55.296 -56.375v40.32q0 1.8 -1.224 3.204t-3.096 2.178 -3.726 1.152 -3.474 0.378 -3.474 -0.378 -3.726 -1.152 -3.096 -2.178 -1.224 -3.204 1.224 -3.204 3.096 -2.178 3.726 -1.152 3.474 -0.378q3.78 0 6.912 1.404v-19.332l-27.648 8.532v25.524q0 1.8 -1.224 3.204t-3.096 2.178 -3.726 1.152 -3.474 0.378 -3.474 -0.378 -3.726 -1.152 -3.096 -2.178 -1.224 -3.204 1.224 -3.204 3.096 -2.178 3.726 -1.152 3.474 -0.378q3.78 0 6.912 1.404v-34.812q0 -1.116 0.684 -2.034t1.764 -1.278l29.952 -9.216q0.432 -0.144 1.008 -0.144 1.44 0 2.448 1.008t1.008 2.448z'}" style="height:500px;width:500px;display:block;" :center="center" :zoom="7">
          <marker v-for="m in markers" :position.sync="m.position" :clickable="true" :draggable="true" @g-click="center=m.center">
          </marker>
        </map>
    </div>
```

Can you suggest a solution based to display the marker based on the json data obtained using url? I am a basic developer and just started.. I am not able to display maps?

Comment: Surely you just update `this.markers` based on the data you received from the AJAX request? Can you show what a response looks like?

Comment: https://n2s.herokuapp.com/api/post/get/5

Comment: So something like `this.markers = [{position: { lat: e.data.lat, lng: e.data.lon}}]` should work, then.

Comment: i tried but getting errors sir

Comment: So tell us _which_ errors. Or edit your paste so we can try to reproduce it ourselves.

Comment: [Vue warn]: Prop "zoom" expects a two-way binding type. (found in component: <map>)

Comment: the above code in the question works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158503/discussion-between-botje-and-wanderer).

Comment: can you solve it